# Sed works differently when run by super user?

Tags: sed, sudo

I have just encountered the most perplexing (for me) phenomenon.

I have a sed one liner

```
sed 's/^(\*Default.*:) Letter/$1 A4/g' /usr/share/ppd/hplip/HP/HP-*
```

This does exactly what I want and replaces "*DefaultPaperDimension: Letter
" with "*DefaultPaperDimension: A4"

But when I run

```
sudo sed 's/^(\*Default.*:) Letter/$1 A4/g' /usr/share/ppd/hplip/HP/HP-*
```

Nothing is matched or replaced. "*DefaultPaperDimension: Letter
" remains "*DefaultPaperDimension: Letter"

WHY IS THIS?? 8-/

Comment: Shouldn't the back reference be `\1` and not `$1`?

Comment: Some old versions of `sed` support `$n` style backreferences, but try it with `\1` instead and see if it works. I can't replicate but I suspect parameter expansion issues are to blame.

Comment: Which sed version and OS/distribution do you use?

Comment: OS = Linux Mint 17.2; Sed = GNU sed 4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments. In searching for the version of sed I discovered that I had created an alias `sed='perl -pe'` which being a user alias not a global one does not affect sudo.

Thus:

```
sed 's/^(\*Default.*:) Letter/$1 A4/g' /usr/share/ppd/hplip/HP/HP-*
```

is actually

```
perl -pe 's/^(\*Default.*:) Letter/$1 A4/g' /usr/share/ppd/hplip/HP/HP-*
```

while

```
sudo sed 's/^(\*Default.*:) Letter/$1 A4/g' /usr/share/ppd/hplip/HP/HP-*
```

Is actual sed and therefore what it appears to be.

Thanks again.